# wrap equadistant sprites to screen maintaining distance

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a fixed set of 9 objects that are equidistant. When they pass off screen right edge, they wrap to screen left.

when object0.x hits the right edge of the screen (720 or 1280) it needs to wrap to the left of object9 which is probably offscreen to the left, and maintain its distance from object9, likewise for the other sprites when they go off screen, they need to wrap to the opposite maintaining distance between the previous object. Same of course needs to be true when moving opposite direction.

Currently, things are wrapping and getting way out of position.

Here is my current code: (getstartpos() is thanks to [petar-ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791998/petar-ivanov))

```
function getstartpos(objectWidth as integer, startPosition as integer, objectNumber as integer, space as integer)

return startPosition + objectNumber * (objectWidth + space)

end function

sub screenupdate()

m.p0x=m.p0x+ int(m.inc)

if m.p0x > 720
    m.p0x   = -getstartpos(120,m.p9x,9,20)
    ?m.p0x
endif

m.p0.MoveTo(m.p0x, m.p0y)

m.p1x = m.p1x + int(m.inc)

if m.p1x > 720
    m.p1x   = -getstartpos(120,m.p0x,0,20)
    ?m.p1x
endif

m.p1.MoveTo(m.p1x, m.p1y)

m.p2x = m.p2x + int(m.inc)

if m.p2x > 720
    m.p2x   = -getstartpos(120,m.p1x,1,20)
    ?m.p2x
endif

m.p2.MoveTo(m.p2x, m.p2y)

...

m.p9x = m.p9x + int(m.inc)  
    if m.p9x > 720
    m.p9x   = -getstartpos(120,m.p8x,8,20)
    ?m.p9x
endif
m.p9.MoveTo(m.p9x, m.p9y)   
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I've done is to base the calculation on the number of objects on the screen and a subset of the screen width - the actual displayed area as opposed to the screen width itself. This seems to work, but since everything is hardcoded, it feels like a "hack" instead of a solution, which would be a formula for doing this for any arbitrary display width and arbitrary object width, but the problem IS solved for immediate situation.

```
m.p0x=m.p0x+ int(m.inc)

if m.p0x > 650 then
    m.p0x   = (m.p5x -125)
    ?"m.p0x moved to:";m.p0x
    ?m.p5x
    ?"difference: ";m.p5x -m.p0x
endif

m.p0.MoveTo(m.p0x, m.p0y)

m.p1x = m.p1x + int(m.inc)

if m.p1x > 650
    m.p1x   = m.p0x-125
endif

m.p1.MoveTo(m.p1x, m.p1y)

m.p2x = m.p2x + int(m.inc)

if m.p2x > 650
    m.p2x   = m.p1x-125     
endif

m.p2.MoveTo(m.p2x, m.p2y)

m.p3x = m.p3x + int(m.inc)

if m.p3x > 650
    m.p3x   = m.p2x-125
endif
m.p3.MoveTo(m.p3x, m.p3y)


m.p4x=m.p4x+ int(m.inc)

if m.p4x > 650
    m.p4x   = m.p3x-125
endif

m.p4.MoveTo(m.p4x, m.p4y)

m.p5x = m.p5x + int(m.inc)

if m.p5x > 650
    m.p5x   =  m.p4x-125
endif

m.p5.MoveTo(m.p5x, m.p5y)

(etc up to m.p9)
```